# I have multiple return statements that require an RJXS Delay. Is there a way to make the operator into a constant?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, operators

For instance, I have the below pseudo code:

```
public action1(): 
    return stuff.pipe(delay(15000)); 

public action2(): 
    return stuff.pipe(delay(15000)); 

public action3(): 
    return stuff.pipe(delay(15000));
```

The delay is identical for each return and will not change. But instead of having it as a static value, I would like to make it into a constant that can be easily referenced and modified if needed. Something like the below pseudo code:

```
Const delay = pipe(delay(15000)) 

public action1(): 
    return stuff.delay; 

public action2(): 
    return stuff.delay; 

public action3(): 
    return stuff.delay;
```

I have tried to directly reference the delay by using const but I am getting errors when attempting this. I am using the RJXS Delay operator. The primary question is, Is there a way to convert this operator into a constant that can be used in multiple areas?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a generic function which will accept observer and and bind delay with it and return.

You can do something like bellow

```ts
const getAfterDelay = (observer) => observer.pipe(delay(15000));

public action1(): 
    return getAfterDelay(stuff); 

public action2(): 
    return getAfterDelay(stuff);  

public action3(): 
    return getAfterDelay(stuff);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Create an Extension Method

```ts
declare module 'rxjs/internal/Observable' {
  interface Observable<T> {
    delay(): Observable<T>;
  }
}

Observable.prototype.delay = function(): Observable<any> {
  return this.pipe(delay(15000));
};
```

This allows for the syntax that you're looking for: `stuff.delay();`.

---

[Observable Delay Extension Method in Typescript](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-rwxnr7?file=index.ts) for StackBlitz example.